# Is this a Jordan domain

Tags: complex-analysis

Is $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}_+$ a Jordan domain? Initially I believed it not be a Jordan domain, but the boundary is given by the curve $$\gamma(t) = \frac{1}{1-t} -1,$$ which is smooth and the derivative does not vanish for $0 < t < 1$. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A half-line is not homeomorphic to the surface of a ball.  So this is not a Jordan domain.